# When I update Meteor from 1.6.1.3 to 1.7, the webbrowser can't load correctly any more

Tags: meteor

host: ubuntu 16.04

meteor: 1.6.1.3

web browser: Firefox 60.0.2 chrome  67.0.3396.87

1. meteor update, it update to 1.7.03

192.168.1.9 is the host ip address

when I visit from anothor host through http://192.168.1.9:3000
the browser gives a tip can't find `/node_modules/meteor/socket-stream-client/sockjs-0.3.4.js` module

and the contents don't load completely.

when I visit in the host through http://127.0.0.1:3000, it loads completely with no error.

execute ROOT_URL=192.168.1.9：3000 meteor

and then visit http://192.168.1.9:3000, from another host the webbrowser can work well.

2.meteor update --release 1.6.1.3
everything goes properly.

The host side don't report any error, I can't fix this problem.

fix by [meteor issuses 10016](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10016)

Comment: This is probably worth opening an issue on the meteor repo: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues

Comment: OK, I'll try it.